# this code of mine has no error but it isnt showing any output

Tags: java

In this code the method setEid isn't working dont know what's the problem with while loop

this code of mine has no error but it isnt showing any output

```
public class Emp {

    private String eid;

    public String getEid() {

        return eid;
    }

    public void setEid(String e) {
        while (e.length() < 12) {
            eid = e;
        }
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Emp z = new Emp();
        z.setEid("rgrge");
        System.out.println("\n" + z.getEid());
    }
}
```

enter code here i expect the static initialization of setEid argument should not take more than 12 characters

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `while(e.length()<12)` in the setter? There's an infinite loop because the length of *rgrge* is **always** less than 12. Did you mean `if`?

Answer (score 2):

Your setter method have a while loop if eid length is less than 12 then it always stuck in this method.

```
public void setEid(String e){
     while(e.length()<12)
        eid=e;
 }
```

and In your main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Emp z=new Emp();
      z.setEid("rgrge"); // you call setter 
      System.out.println("\n"+z.getEid());
}
```

you pass `"rgrge"` in setter and its length is less than 12. Tht's why your program is stuck in loop and not showing any thing.

Change setter implementation to this.

```
public void setEid(String e){
   if(e.length()<12) // change while to if
        eid=e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so first there should have had `if` instead of `while`.

> Change:

`while(e.length()<12)` change this as `if(e.length()<12)`

> Explanation:

your `setEid` method never going to run because there is no break condition there. your `while loop` condition tends to the infinite. your code gets stuck in that while loop.

here you passed `z.setEid("rgrge");`. in your example, Length of `string e` is `5` which is obviously less than 12, so the condition will always be satisfied and your program will be stuck in infinite loop.